# Циклы в python (анализ данных)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Всем добрый день, у меня есть такой код (я горе програмист, но я стараюсь)

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

dataset_path = r"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Robotu\EURUSD_zagrusit.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path)


# Убираем ненужные данные
df = df.drop(["TIME"], axis=1)
df = df.drop(["HIGH"], axis=1)
df = df.drop(["LOW"], axis=1)
# print(df.head(5))


# Записываем OPEN and CLOSE в массивы
Open = []
Close = []

for i in df["OPEN"]:
    Open.append(i)

for i in df["CLOSE"]:
    Close.append(i)


# Промаркируем бары (Бычий - 2, Медвежий - (-1), Нулевой - 0)
Prom_massiv = [(Close - Open) for Close, Open in zip(Close, Open)]
Markirovka_barov = []

for i in Prom_massiv:
    if i > 0:
        Markirovka_barov.append(2)
    elif i < 0:
        Markirovka_barov.append(-1)
    else:
        Markirovka_barov.append(0)

# print("Массив с индексами баров (какой именно бар)", Markirovka_barov)
# print(Counter(Markirovka_barov))

# Получим список индексов на которых произошел разворот бара
Indeksu_razvorot = []

Prom_sres_1 = Markirovka_barov[:-1]
Prom_sres_2 = Markirovka_barov[1:]

PM_2 = [abs(Prom_sres_2 - Prom_sres_1) for Prom_sres_2, Prom_sres_1 in zip(Prom_sres_2, Prom_sres_1)]

for i in range(len(PM_2)):
    if PM_2[i] != 0:
        Indeksu_razvorot.append(i+1)

# print("Получили индексы смены свечей", Indeksu_razvorot)
# print(len(Indeksu_razvorot))


# Получим индексы свечей разворота, которые точно либо медвежии либо бычии
PM_3 = []                                     # - Дельта между ценами, для проверки реально ли это поглощение
for i in Indeksu_razvorot:
    PM_3.append(Close[i] - Open[i-1])


PM_4 = []                                     # - Маркировки свечей, которые поменялись
for i in Indeksu_razvorot:
    PM_4.append(Markirovka_barov[i])

print("Дельта между ценами, для проверки реально ли это поглощение", PM_3)
print("Маркировки свечей, которые поменялись", PM_4)
# print(len(PM_3), len(PM_4))

Itog_indeksu_poglos = []                               # - Итоговые индексы свечей, которые точно, либо мед-погл, б-п
for i in range(len(PM_4)):
    if PM_4[i] < 0 and PM_3[i] < 0:
        Itog_indeksu_poglos.append(Indeksu_razvorot[i])
    elif PM_4[i] > 0 and PM_3[i] > 0:
        Itog_indeksu_poglos.append(Indeksu_razvorot[i])
    else:
        break

print("Итоговые индексы свечей, которые точно, либо мед-погл либо быч-поглощ", Itog_indeksu_poglos)
```

У меня не работает только последняя часть кода, остальное проверял, помогите плз вот с этой частью:

```
tog_indeksu_poglos = []                               # - Итоговые индексы свечей, которые точно, либо мед-погл, б-п
for i in range(len(PM_4)):
    if PM_4[i] < 0 and PM_3[i] < 0:
        Itog_indeksu_poglos.append(Indeksu_razvorot[i])
    elif PM_4[i] > 0 and PM_3[i] > 0:
        Itog_indeksu_poglos.append(Indeksu_razvorot[i])
    else:
        break

print("Итоговые индексы свечей, которые точно, либо мед-погл либо быч-поглощ", Itog_indeksu_poglos)
```

выдает просто пустой массив

```
Итоговые индексы свечей, которые точно, либо мед-погл либо быч-поглощ []
```

Буду очень благодарен, если подскажите, как в начале где дропаю колонки в ДФ, как дропнуть в одну строчку, а не как у меня

Заранее благодарен

Comment: Вчера писал этотже код, просто на маленьких тестовых данных, а сегодня, делаю на реальном примере и эта часть кода уже не работает

Comment: Проверяй по шагам все, что влияет на Itog_indeksu_poglos: пустой ли список Indeksu_razvorot, выполняются ли условия в цикле for. Либо выкладывай где-нибудь EURUSD_zagrusit.csv - гляну.

Comment: @AlexP https://yadi.sk/d/wuvSw8cauXQuSw выгрузил вот сюда исходные данные, заранее огромное спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых:

```
df = df.drop(["TIME"], axis=1)
df = df.drop(["HIGH"], axis=1)
df = df.drop(["LOW"], axis=1)
```

можно заменить на:

```
df = df.drop(["TIME", "HIGH", "LOW"], axis=1)
```

Во-вторых, в последнем цикле сразу срабатывает последнее условие и происходит выход из цикла по break. Отсюда и пустой список. Уберите последнее условие, чтобы было как то так:

```
for i in range(len(PM_4)):
    if PM_4[i] < 0 and PM_3[i] < 0:
        Itog_indeksu_poglos.append(Indeksu_razvorot[i])
    elif PM_4[i] > 0 and PM_3[i] > 0:
        Itog_indeksu_poglos.append(Indeksu_razvorot[i])
```

Comment: большое вам спасибо, логично и по делу, спасибо)

Comment: Да не за что) Успехов вам.

Comment: сейчас более кошерным/халяльным способом считается `df.drop(columns=["TIME", "HIGH", "LOW"])` ;)

Comment: Большое спасибо